# Solving complex cubic equation $-2az^2z^*+2bz^*-icz/2=0$ with $a$ and $c$ real and $b$ imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, problem-solving

Hi I'm trying to solve the following complex cubic root equation for $z$
$$
-2az^2z^*+2bz^*-i\frac{c}{2}z=0\qquad a,c\in\Re \text{, } b\in\Im
$$
By inspection it is easy to see that one of the roots that solve the equation is $z=0$. To find the other two roots I've been writing $z$ in polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$ and dividing by $z$, so
$$
-2ar^2+2be^{-i2\theta}-i\frac{c}{2}=0
$$
From this I find that $r=\pm\Big(\frac{b}{a}e^{-i2\theta}-i\frac{c}{4a}\Big)^{1/2}$

Now I'm unsure what to do next, I would like to find an expression for $\theta$. So I was thinking of asking the question what value of $\theta$ makes $r=0$? I.e.
$$
0=\frac{b}{a}e^{-i2\theta}-i\frac{c}{4a}\Rightarrow-i2\theta=\log(i\frac{c}{b})
$$ 
I mean normally you would define $\theta$ as 
$$
\theta=arg (z)=\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})
$$
if $z=x+iy$ when you transform to polar form, but is it correct what I have done thus far?

Comment: is $$z*=\bar{z}$$

Comment: $z^*$ is the Conjugate of $z$ i.e. if $z=x+iy$ then $z^*=x-iy$

Comment: You start to err right after obtaining $$-2ar^2+2be^{-i2\theta}-ic/2=0$$ but before that, you are correct, so let us start from this point, **equating to 0 the real and the imaginary parts**: it seems that $a$ and $c$ are real and $b=id$ with $d$ real, hence $$-2ar^2+2id(\cos(2\theta)-i\sin(2\theta))-ic/2=0$$ yields the pair of equations $$-2ar^2+2d\sin(2\theta)=0\qquad2d\cos(2\theta)-c/2=0$$ hence $$\cos(2\theta)=c/(4d)$$ and $$r^2=d\sin(2\theta)/a=|d/a|\sqrt{1-\cos^2(2\theta)}=|d/a|\sqrt{1-c^2/(4d)^2}$$ hence $r$ is fully determined and one gets a finite number of solutions for $\theta$.